# SQLite fts3: search for a string in a column

Tags: sqlite, fts3

Is there any way to search for a particular string in a column?

I want to search like SELECT * from email_fts WHERE email_fts MATCH 'to:"a@b.com" OR from:"c@d.com"'

Thanks in advance,

Manoj

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you create proper FTS columns in the FTS index:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE email_fts USING fts3(subject, body, "to", "from");
```

And then you can search individual FTS columns:

```
SELECT  rowid 
FROM    email_fts 
WHERE   "to" MATCH 'a@b.com'

UNION

SELECT  rowid 
FROM    email_fts 
WHERE   "from" MATCH 'c@d.com'
```

*EDIT*: My previous answer had an `OR` in the `WHERE` clause.  Apparently sqlite doesn't support combining `OR` queries with `MATCH` conditions.  The above union works.

FTS docs are here, this is one of the examples used in the docs.

http://sqlite.org/fts3.html

Comment: Not able to find a related doc.


I got error like this:


sqlite> .schema email_fts


CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [email_fts] USING fts3 (


[from],


[subject],


[body],


[to],


[cc],


[filename]


sqlite> SELECT * FROM email_FTS WHERE "to" MATCH 'a@b.com' OR "from" 
MATCH 'b@c.
com';


SQL error: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context


sqlite>

Comment: @Manoj, I didn't realize sqlite doesn't support combining `OR` with `MATCH`.  Strange.  I updated the answer to use a `UNION` which works fine.  If you need to combine with non-FTS data you can wrap the union in a subquery and join that on other tables.