# A limitation of Sqlite3's full text search doesn't allow ORs with MATCHes. Workaround?

Tags: sqlite, fts3

Sqlite3's full text search facility - FTS3 - allows to use MATCH operator for fast full-text search:

```
SELECT ItemId FROM docs WHERE docs.text MATCH 'linux'
```

However, it does not support OR operator anywhere in an SQL query where there's a MATCH (source: [1](http://osdir.com/ml/sqlite-users/2010-03/msg00074.html), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621308/sqlite-fts3-search-for-a-string-in-a-column)):

```
SELECT ItemId FROM docs WHERE docs.text MATCH 'linux' OR column=value
error: unable to use function MATCH in the requested context
```

(Not to be confused with OR operator in the FTS3 query itself, i.e. `SELECT ItemId FROM docs WHERE docs.text MATCH 'linux OR unix'`. This works fine.)

Is there a way to rewrite the query so that it works (even if it's somewhat slower)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting the query using temporary views will work as expected:

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW view1 AS SELECT ItemId FROM docs WHERE docs.text MATCH 'linux' 
SELECT * FROM docs WHERE ItemId IN view1 OR column=value
DROP VIEW view1
```

The speed will be comparable to that of a "direct" query (without the temporary view) if the temporary view is not "sweeping", i.e. it does not generate a lot of rows.