# How to include null values in an SQLite FTS3 Match Query?

Tags: android, sqlite, match, android-sqlite, fts3

I'm programming for the Android, using  SQLITE's FTS3 tables (virtual tables).  Is there any way to have a query return null values in the same query one uses the MATCH statement?

As an example, i have tried the following:

```
Select rowid, Category From 'MyTable' Where Category IS NULL OR Category Match 'Term1 OR Term2 OR Term3 -Term4'
```

I got a run time error; apparently I can't combine them.

I have also tried including various match inputs like '', "", ''''', """"", 0, NULL, etc to try to get the match function to include Null values.  Can't find any documentation if there is a special parameter to include.

Any ideas?

Comment: What runtime error are you getting?

Comment: 1. unable to use function MATCH in the requested context, db=xxx
2. exception: SQL logic error or missing database;

Comment: Hm, silly double check, are you sure the version you're running has FTS3 enabled? Does it work without the null check?

Comment: Works for me. Check the output of `pragma compile_options;` for `ENABLE_FTS3`.

Comment: I only intended to show it as something that doesn't work, as to why i'm looking for a workaround.  Several other questions [(link here)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764357/a-limitation-of-sqlite3s-full-text-search-doesnt-allow-ors-with-matches-worka) indicate that MATCH cannot work with an OR operator outside of the MATCH statement.  Not sure how you got it to work?  If its because of the pragma settings, not sure it will help me because I'm not compiling SQLite but using the built-in version for android for my app.

Comment: Okay figured out a workaround by looking at the answer [here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621308/sqlite-fts3-search-for-a-string-in-a-column).  You can combine two select statements with a union, e.g.

SELECT  rowid, category 
FROM    MyTable 
WHERE   category IS NULL

UNION

SELECT  rowid, category 
FROM    MyTable 
WHERE   category MATCH 'term1 OR term2 OR term3 -Term4'

If we could find the nulls as one of the terms in the Match statement, that would be the most efficient, but haven't found a way to do that yet.